# Undefined variable: conn in

Tags: php, function, variables, undefined

I made this script yesterday at my home and it worked fine.
And now its not working here in my job.

i'm getting this erro...

> Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\cef\login_sys.php
>   on line 10
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cef\login_sys.php on line 10.

here is the script for login_sys.php

```
<?php

include 'includes/dbh.php';

$email= $_POST['email'];
$password= $_POST['password'];


$sql =("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email='$email' AND    
 password='$password'");                          
 $result = $conn->query($sql);
 if(!$row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 echo "Your information is invalid!! <br>
 or user is not in our server = (
";

  }else{

$_SESSION['id']= $row['id'];
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])){
      echo $_SESSION['id'];

      }else{
          echo "Your not logged in";

          }

 //header("Location: central.php");

 }
 ?>
```

here is the inclued folder with my conn variable the includes/dbh.php...

```
 //$servername = "***";
 //$username = "***";
 //$password = "****";
 //$dbname = "***";

 //create the connection
 $conn = mysqli_connect ('***', '**', '***', '***');
 if(!$conn) {
 die("Connection faild: ".mysqli_connect_error());  
 }

 ?>
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: you sure copied all the same files and the same db connection file? check your path also and make sure you started the session. use http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Ok James.... you have answers below but that isn't the problem here. If you took off somewhere, for something your boss needs you to do (or whatever other reason), then I probably won't be here by the time you get back. Again, look at my first comment. Edit: Oh, I see you're only responding to answers. Ok, I'm done here, good luck.

Comment: other thing is that i have the same files in difrent folders and there are the same.in my folder .../cef. i was trying to use the login_sys from that folder. but then i change my link to C:\xampp\htdocs\mytest\login_sys.php... and worked fine...but the weird thing is why it didnt work, if all the files are the same? 
Everythinh i working now btw lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are tryng to invoke the query method of the class mysqli on a descriptor. 
Use

```
$conn=new mysqli('','','','');
```

instead of

```
$conn=mysqli_connect();
```

Comment: You 100% sure about that? They'd get a different error message if that were the case.

Comment: i think mysqli_connect is the procedural way to use mysqli. And the error seems to refer about the fact that $conn is not an object

Comment: Object oriented and procedural do work together. Not recommended, but nonetheless, it still works. The error here is `Notice: Undefined variable: conn`.

Comment: or maybe yes, i'm wrong. Sorry

Comment: maybe is an scope issue.  try with `global $conn;`

Comment: i looking here at my download folder and i've downloaded xammp 5.5.35 / PHP. At my house i was using xammp with php7.Maybe it could be that.Now im downloading the latest version.could this be the reason of all this?

Comment: @RiccardoBonafede variable scope is only when a custom function is used and that wasn't in the guy's code.

Comment: i know, but if it can't find that var it means that it wasn't declared. So maybe he hasn't pasted all the code

Comment: other thing is that i have the same files in difrent folders and there are the same.in my folder .../cef.   i was trying to use the login_sys from that folder. but then i change my link to C:\xampp\htdocs\mytest\login_sys.php... and worked fine...but the weird thing is why it didnt work, if all the files are the same?

Comment: i found the problem.in my folder cef i had my dbh.php  starting with <?php and in my folder mytest i hade my dbh.php starting with <?   but i didnt put the php after the interrogation point....so that was why it made a big mess...btw a huge thx for you tips o/